# Protobuf-net Runtime serialization

Tags: protobuf-net

```
[ProtoContract]
public abstract class Animal
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public abstract string Type { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public int Likeability { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public override string Type { get; set; }
    public int Friendliness { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Type : {0}, Name : {1}, Likeability : {2}, Friendliness : {3}", Type, Name, Likeability, Friendliness);
    }
}
```

use case i.e.

```
var animal = new Cat() { Name = "Whiskers", Friendliness = 10 , Type = "cat", Likeability = 5};
var model = TypeModel.Create();
model[typeof(Animal)].AddSubType(4, typeof(Cat));
model[typeof(Cat)].AddField(1, "Friendliness");
var typeModel = model.Compile();

var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
typeModel.Serialize(memoryStream, animal);

var deserializedCat = new Cat() { Name = "PusPus" };
memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var deserializedCat1 = typeModel.Deserialize(memoryStream, deserializedCat, typeof(Cat));
Console.WriteLine("deserializedCat : hash : " + deserializedCat.GetHashCode() + "\n" + deserializedCat);
Console.WriteLine("deserializedCat1 : hash : " + deserializedCat1.GetHashCode() + "\n" + deserializedCat1);
```

Is the above use case correct for reusable runtime serialization or should one explicitly map the "Cat" ignoring the "Animal" and Also a bit confused w.r.t "ComplileInPlace" how does it differ from Compile ?

Comment: looks fine to me, except i don't know why you're using both the old and the new way of tagging attributes. I just use ProtoContract and ProtoMember on all objects i want to serialize, also you're missing a `[ProtoContract]` on your `Cat` class. don't know about compile in place.

Comment: @Joe I think the point here is that `Cat` isn't known in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of mapping at runtime, that looks fine. Does it work as expected? i.e. do you get a cat back? and both the `Animal` and `Cat` members?

Differences in the `Compile*` methods:

- `CompileInPlace()` makes the *existing* model, such that future calls to `model.Serialize(...)` will use the serialized form. Normally this is automatic anyway the first time each type is required, but this allows it to be prepared ahead of time; the "in place" approach also has extra features - it can access private members, and it can do extra stack tricks for small performance tweaks - but it is not available on all platforms
- `Compile(string,string)` allows you to compile the model to a separate dll file, which can be referenced and used for fully-static serialization (i.e. no reflection at runtime)
- `Compile()` does something *like* that, but creates an instance of a `TypeModel` built from the model, without a separate dll file

In most cases, `CompileInPlace()` is what you are after - although you don't need to do anything at all, since it will usually automatically compile-in-place when needed

Comment: yes it does work fine, just wanted to be sure about the use case, w.r.t CompileInPlace availability only on certain platforms, which platforms are supported ?

Comment: @kalki if the method is there, it should work. I don't think 1.1 supports CompileInPlace (no DynamicMethod), for example.